# How to pass id value from JSP to select query as input before submit?

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to get ID value in scriptlet before submit?.
My actual scenario is ---   I created one JSP page, in which employee ID is the input. Now on blur, I want to get this ID and pass it to a SQL query for validation. Is it possible to send the ID value to SQL before submitting the form? If so, please guide me accordingly with example. If I use, `request.getParameter` the ID value is coming as `null`.

Comment: Please provide some of your code. There are many ways of doing these if my view point in your question is same with your's. If possible avoid using scriptlet. See here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Answer (score 1):

Send an ajax request. [jQuery](http://jquery.org) is extremely helpful in this. Kickoff example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#id").blur(function() {
                    $.getJSON("validateId", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                        $("#id_message").text(data.valid ? '' : 'invalid!');
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .error { color: red; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="someservlet" method="post">
            <label for="id">id</label>
            <input id="id" name="id" />
            <span id="id_message" class="error"></span>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

With a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/validateId` and does the following in `doGet()` method:

```
boolean valid = validateId(request.getParameter("id"));
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write("{valid:" + valid "}");
```

That's it. The `validateId()` method example should of course do the DB job and return `true` or `false` depending on the outcome.

*Note that you still need to perform the same validation in the server side in the servlet behind URL `someservlet`. JavaScript is namely disableable/spoofable/hackable. When the server side validation fails, just put the message in a map in the request scope, let the servlet redisplay the JSP and let the JSP display the message using EL.*

```
            <span id="id_message" class="error">${messages.id}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

... yes, through use of javascript, your ajax call will have to talk to the server, no sample here but you should be able to find lots of examples with a little 'googling'